# Apache ssl.conf RewriteRule

Tags: apache-2.2

The stuff after the #### are just to tell you what I am doing and it's not actually part of my ssl.conf file

Trying to modify an ssl.conf configuration to do the following...

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/$
RewriteRule ^/(.*) https://misc.org/scores [L,R=301] 
# takes misc.org and makes it misc.org/scores

#1 
RewriteRule ^/scores/liverpool https://misc2.org/liverpool2 [L,R=301]
# redirect for '/scores/liverpool to misc2.org/liverpool2' works

#2 
RewriteRule ^/scores/liverpool/child https://misc2.org/liverpool2/child [L,R=301]
# only redirects to /misc2.org/liverpool2 and never makes it to /misc2.org/liverpool2/child
```

If I comment out #1...#2 works but I need both to work.

What am I missing?

Thanks in advance

Comment: You're putting them in the wrong order. Put the most specific one first.

Answer (score 0):

Try to put rule `#2` before rule `#1` as rule `#1` already matches path `/scores/liverpool/child` which is then redirected to `https://misc2.org/liverpool2`.

Or alternatively remove rule `#1` and `#2` and use instead:

```
RewriteRule ^/scores/liverpool(.*) https://misc2.org/liverpool2$1 [L,R=301]
```